type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<Object>' of 'function result'
I have this code to show posts on my feed:
class Post {
  final String username;
  final String description;
  final ImageProvider profileImageUrl;

  Post({required this.username, required this.description, required this.profileImageUrl});
}

List<Post> posts = [
  Post(username: 'John Doe', description: 'Hello world!', profileImageUrl: Image.network('https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/16/27/58/360_F_516275801_f3Fsp17x6HQK0xQgDQEELoTuERO4SsWV.jpg').image),
];

Then later on I try to show this image:
SizedBox(
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    foregroundImage: posts[index].profileImageUrl,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
),

Which results in the following error:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider' of 'function result'
If I change it to this:
foregroundImage: posts[index].profileImageUrl ?? Image.network('https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/16/27/58/360_F_516275801_f3Fsp17x6HQK0xQgDQEELoTuERO4SsWV.jpg').image,

my SDK says:

The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never
executed. Try removing the operator and the right operand.

What am I missing here?

have you tried to pass a direct ImageProvider like NetworkImage rather than Image.network(...).image because this image property is related to resizing an image.

The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed. This error occurs because the profileImageUrl variable in your Post class is non-nullable, meaning it always has a value. If you make profileImageUrl nullable, you can add a condition where, if profileImageUrl is null, the right operand is used and displayed in the UI.
class Post {
  final String username;
  final String description;
  final ImageProvider? profileImageUrl;

  Post({required this.username, required this.description, required this.profileImageUrl});
}

List<Post> posts = [
  Post(username: 'John Doe', description: 'Hello world!', profileImageUrl: Image.network('https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/16/27/58/360_F_516275801_f3Fsp17x6HQK0xQgDQEELoTuERO4SsWV.jpg').image),
];


After that you can add your condition it won't gave you warning. If you assign null to profileImageUrl in your list then also works.
SizedBox(
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  child: CircleAvatar(
    foregroundImage: posts[index].profileImageUrl ?? Image.network('https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/05/16/27/58/360_F_516275801_f3Fsp17x6HQK0xQgDQEELoTuERO4SsWV.jpg').image,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  ),
),

